# fancybox не применяется слайдер к галерее

Tags: javascript, fancybox

пытаюсь применить плагин fancybox для галереи, чтобы при клике на одну из картинок открывалось модальное окно, в котором будет слайдер.

Проблема следующая: плагин применяется, модальное окно открывается, но только с одной картинкой, листать ничего нельзя.

```
<div class="column-4 column-sm-6 column-to-xs-12">
  <img src="{Путь к изображению}">
</div>
<div class="column-4 column-sm-6 column-to-xs-12">
  <img src="{Путь к изображению}">
</div>
<div class="column-4 column-sm-6 column-to-xs-12">
  <img src="{Путь к изображению}">
</div>
```

вот js:

```
$(function(){
  $(".gallery img").each(function(){
     $(this).parent()
        .addClass('gal')
        .attr({
         'rel': 'group',
         'href': $(this).attr('src')
      });
  });
  $(".gal").fancybox()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение: у каждой картинки должен был быть контейнер `<a>` а не `<div>`

Comment: Удалите вопрос, нажав на ссылку под метками.

Comment: Опишите решение проблемы более детально, что бы другие пользователи знали, как вы решили её.Что бы редактировать сообщение, нажмите [edit]

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/146201)

Comment: @Other зачем удалять вопрос?

Comment: @rjhdby вряд ли автор сам у себя просит внести уточнения ))

Comment: Автор, я поддерживаю комментарий Yuri: расскажите подробнее, как задачу решили. Пример кода был бы очень полезен. (Кстати, чуток отформатировал ответ, а то неэкранированные теги «съедались».)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, можно и так, хотя тут желательно объяснить еще *почему* так, чтобы была ценность для потомков.